# How to make saveRow function wait for editRow function in jqGrid

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

Im trying to adapt jqGrid add function to my own purposes. I have navButton  that I want to make a specific behavior:

1. When user click that button, new row, in edit mode appears on the
   grid.
2. When user type data, and click enter, then data is send to
       server.

Right now, my code looks like this:

```
 .navButtonAdd("#${pagerId}", {
                caption: "${resolveMessage('assign')}", 
                buttonicon: "ui-icon-add", 
                onClickButton: function() {
                 if (assignMode == false){
                    assignMode = true;
                    $('#${tableId}').jqGrid('addRowData', 0, {});
                    $('#${tableId}').jqGrid('editRow', 0);
                    $('#${tableId}').jqGrid('saveRow', 0, function(){ assignMode = false; }, "${assignURL}"); 
                 }
                },
                position:"last"
            })
```

My problem is that saveRow function is not waiting for the end of editRow. It send empty data to server after the button is clicked immediately. How to made saveRow to wait for typed data?

Comment: version of jqgrid?

Comment: version is  jqGrid  5.1.0

Comment: http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:inline_editing see this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend you to use [inlineNav](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:inline_editing#inlinenav) instead of re-implementing the same functionality yourself. For example, you current code, for example uses the same rowid `0` for every added row, which is very bad. Moreover you call `editRow` without any additional options and then call `saveRow` *immediately after* `editRow` which force saving the empty row with probably wrong data. Saving can fail during validation.

Moreover I'd recommend you to consider to use [free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid) available for free under MIT or GNU GPLv2 licenses instead of usage commercial Guriddo jqGrid JS (see the prices [here](http://guriddo.net/?page_id=103334)). I develop free jqGrid fork since the end of 2014 (short after [the post](http://www.trirand.com/blog/?p=1438)) and have implemented really many fixes, improvements and new features described shortly in readmes to every published version, [wiki articles](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/wiki) and the answers on the steckoverflow which I posted at the time.